# Null pointer with hashmap containing multiple keys

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` in my `HashMap` containing multiple keys. I was having issues with memory and tried to condense my code without creating unnecessary variables, so I've tried doing it this way:

```
        HashMap<String,HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>> data    =   new HashMap<>();

        data
        .put(user, new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>())
        .put(info, new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>());
```

I'm getting the `NullPointerException` on:

```
.put(info, new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>());
```

Any idea why? Do I have to create the variables first?

Comment: Putting two .put would just add two entries to the first key, I need to add entries to the second key as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.put(user, new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>())` would return null if the `user` key wasn't already in the map. Otherwise it would return the old value that was associated with that key.

You should **NOT** chain your `put` calls. Even if you don't get `NullPointerException`, you wouldn't get the behavior you want, since the second `put` (`.put(info, new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>())`) would be performed on the old value. Beside being wrong, it also makes your code less readable.

You must use an additional variable :

```
    HashMap<String,HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>> 
      data = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> 
      map2 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>();
    data.put(user, map2);
    map2.put(info, new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>());
```

Comment: An additional variable ... or alternatively, the evil, double-brace notation.

Comment: Damn thought so. Thanks for the answer, just one additional question regarding this: is this acceptable practice, to have many hashmaps and arraylists in the values? And could you give any tips for memory management when dealing with this?

Comment: My tip, @joe - make your code as readable as possible.  You're not going to save lots of memory by squashing it up and not introducing variables.  What you are going to do, if you don't target readability, is make it hideously expensive to maintain.

Comment: @joe Perhaps you should consider flattening your structure to a Map<String,User>. The User class can contain all the data relevant to a user. It might even contain instances of additional classes (such as UserInfo) if necessary. It's very hard to understand your code with all those nested maps.

Answer (score 0):

As per the java docs `HashMap.put(K key, V value)` returns

```
 the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.
 (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  HashMap<String,HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>> data    =   new HashMap<>();

    data
    .put(user, new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>())
    .put(info, new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>());
```